# Is there a target package list for Ubuntu phone?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, phone

I know it's not released yet.  I know it's subject to change.

The question is, if I'm trying to make one of the first 100 apps for Ubuntu phone that aren't horrible, what libraries can I expect to depend on?

Like if someone at Canonical working on the project has a dev-phone, what is the output of `dpkg --get-selections`?

I think getting at least a "probably this" list out there might get people developing less trivial applications for the phone earlier, even if the list is subject to change.

**Update**
Ubuntu touch landed...so maybe a package list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is still being finalized, we should have a pretty good answer by the time the Nexus Galaxy images and source code is released

Comment: The image is out and you had the first answer.  Fair opportunity to dump a package list before another answer gets added.